# spring MVC ambiguous mapping error

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC, I have a controller displaying a single user detail or
all the users as a list

```
  // without passing any parameter the app should display all users 
  @RequestMapping("/user")
  public String listUsers(Model m) {
    List<User> users = userService.getUsers();
    m.addAttribute(users);
    return "userlist";
  }

  //same url but with userId parameter, the app displays a single user  detail 
  @RequestMapping("/user")
  public String userDetail(@RequestParam("userId") String userId, Model m)
      throws IOException {
    User user = userService.getUserById(userId);
    m.addAttribute(user);
    return "user_detail";
  }
```

in fact I got a error "spring ambiguous mapping", my mapping syntax is definitely wrong, my question is my desired functionality can be achieved 
in Spring or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it would be correct to specify list request as

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
```

and specific user request as

```
@RequestMapping("/user/{userId}")
```

by passing userId as path parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can correct second method like

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/user/{userId}"})
  public String userDetail(@PathVariable String userId, Model m)
      throws IOException {
    User user = userService.getUserById(userId);
    m.addAttribute(user);
    return "user_detail";
  }
```